# I want to fetch report using my default sandbox QB app. How could i send GET request to reports using v3-php-sdk-2.1.0?

Tags: php, sdk, report, quickbooks

I want to fetch report from my default sandbox QB app. I have successfully logged in and have all data like token etc. Now how could i send GET request report using v3-php-sdk-2.1.0 mentioned in following URL?

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0400_references/reports/profitandloss#/Making_the_Request

I want to fetch report from my default sandbox QB app. How could i send GET request report using v3-php-sdk-2.1.0?

Followed this one /questions/23232279/php-sdk-v3-reporting-issues

I now trying to fetch simple account with following request header (which seems same as give here: developer(.)intuit(.)com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=Account under read call )

["headers_sent"]=> string(657) "GET /v3/company/1421610450/account/12 HTTP/1.1 host: sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com user-agent: V3PHPSDK2.1 accept: application/json connection: close content-type: application/json Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_nonce="xxxxx",oauth_timestamp="1440907935",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="a:2:{s:18:"oauth_token_secret";s:40:"xxxxx";s:11:"oauth_token";s:48:"xxxxx";}",oauth_signature="xxxxx""

And body received by oauth is

["body_recv"]=> string(675) " message=BadRequest; errorCode=003202; statusCode=400 Invalid uri 'https://oauth.intuit.net/iam/oauth_utils/v1/consumers/qyprdgehPU17WVK6BTQ54kVDfYRLFP/access_tokens/a:2:{s:18:"oauth_token_secret";s:40:"xxxxxxxxx";s:11:"oauth_token";s:48:"xxxxxxxxx";}': escaped absolute path not valid " : escaped absolute path not valid "

Here are my sdk.config (I am fetching keys and secret from my own config file thats why not set in it)

```
<ipp>

  <security mode="OAuth">

    <oauth consumerKey="" consumerToken="" accessKey="" accessToken=""  />

  </security>

  <message>

    <request serializationFormat="Xml" compressionFormat="None"/>

    <response serializationFormat="Xml" compressionFormat="None"/>

  </message>

  <service>

    https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" qbo="https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" ipp="https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/" />

  </service>

  <logger>

    <requestLog enableRequestResponseLogging="true" requestResponseLoggingDirectory="/IdsLogs" />

  </logger>

  <!--

    Available strategies are file, handler and export.

    file - saves response into temporary file in system temp folder. 

           The file should be removed manually



    handler - saves response into temporary file and provides file handler.

              The file is automatically removed after script termination or when developer closes the handler

    export - saves response into export folder. Additional parameter "exportDirectory" should be specified

       <contentWriter strategy="export" exportDirectory="/path/to/target/folder">  

    For advance usage you can specify returnObject="true" to work with instance of contentWriter                

  -->

  <contentWriter strategy="file" prefix="ipp"/>

  <specialConfiguration>

      <TaxService jsonOnly="true"/>

  </specialConfiguration>

  <minorVersion>2</minorVersion>

</ipp>
```

```
<!--Intuit Anywhere QBD-->

<!--Specify AccessToken Value for QBD-->

<add key="AccessTokenQBD" value="" />

<!--Specify accessTokenSecret Value for QBD-->

<add key="AccessTokenSecretQBD" value="" />

<!--Specify consumerKey Value for QBD-->

<add key="ConsumerKeyQBD" value="" />

<!--Specify consumerSecret Value for QBD-->

<add key="ConsumerSecretQBD" value="" />

<!--Specify realmIdIA Value for QBD-->

<add key="RealmIAQBD" value="" />

<!--Intuit Anywhere QBO-->

<!--Specify AccessToken Value for QBO-->

<add key="AccessTokenQBO" value="" />

<!--Specify accessTokenSecret Value for QBO-->

<add key="AccessTokenSecretQBO" value=""  />

<!--Specify consumerKey Value for QBO-->

<add key="ConsumerKeyQBO" value="" />

<!--Specify consumerSecret Value for QBO-->

<add key="ConsumerSecretQBO" value="" />

<!--Specify realmIdIA Value for QBO-->

<add key="RealmIAQBO" value="" />
```

While config.php remains unchanged in v3-php-sdk-2.1.0 (NOTE i also checked it using v3-php-sdk-2.0.5 but same results)

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was because your sample oauth code was saving token by serializing accessToken

$access_token = $oauth->getAccessToken( $this->CI->config->item('OAUTH_ACCESS_URL'), '', $this->CI->input->get('oauth_verifier') );
$this->CI->session->set_userdata('token', serialize( $access_token ));

AND we need it like below to make further calls

$token = unserialize($this->CI->session->userdata('token'));
$requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator($token["oauth_token"],                                                          $token["oauth_token_secret"],
$this->CI->config->item('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY'),                                                                          $this->CI->config->item('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET'));

This code is specific to codeigniter Library